# Connect django website/database with desktop application

Tags: django, tkinter

So I am creating a sign up page in django that will also have a sqLite database which won't be accessible from the webpages to the users.

As I want it to be only accessible with the desktop application. After reading up I came across an article that said that Tkinter and django don't mix together.

What can I use instead of tkinter for the application? And what else am I missing in this picture?

1. database? (check)
2. desktop application (????)

server side will only provide the info for the client side and 'reward users'
client side will do the tasks and handshake with the server on completion for 'reward'

Comment: There's nothing preventing tkinter and django from sharing a database - the database doesn't care what type of applications are accessing it. Have you tried connecting your tkinter application to the sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

**Have you considered [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) for the desktop app?** Electron is basically a framework for using web technologies to build desktop applications and is used for things like Slack and Visual Studio Code.

It seems perfect for this purpose. You could just create a custom app in Django for the management of the database that can only be accessed via the Electron client. The entire desktop application could be built as a webpage and justed linked to in Electron.

Comment: Hi, wouldn't just using JSON help in my situation as well? or is that limited in terms of user edits (like add,remove data in the database)